# Why do i get "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ..." exception

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I create a database in SQL Server 2008 Express (Advanced). Then i have a connection string in my C# using 'SharpDevelop' IDE,  Version : 3.2.0.5777, .NET Version         : 2.0.50727.3615

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\SpringTesting.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True' providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When application tries to connect to this database (SpringTesting), i get this exception

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\STS_Client\SpringEfficiency\TestProject1\bin\Release\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

I am not doing anything related to ASP.NET. Any ideas on how to prevent this ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 2):

The connection string that you are using is telling SQL to attach the database. Since you have already created the database it is complaining.

Change the connection string to connect to the database you have created:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SpringTesting;Integrated Security=True;
```

Comment: Thanks but i did that and get the same error. There are responses to this problem on the web but they have too many things that we need to try out !

Comment: I seemed to have messed up by having overlapping installations. I also messed up the un-installations a bit. So i finally removed all SQL components from the Registry (http://www.gilham.org/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=aab85845-88d2-4091-8088-a6bbce0a4304&ID=190)  and deleted the SQL Server folder in Program files. The Configuration options just wouldn't go from the Start-Program . Anyway after removing all traces of SQL that i could possibly find (also used msiinv and smartmsizap for good measure), i managed to re-install SQL Server Express 2005 works fine. Your connection string workfine.